# Save as web page using php

Tags: php, file, save

How to save a web page using php similar to save as in Browser -> file -> save page as
I need to save web page dynamically when url is given as parameter. Containing the images in related folder.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @OscarJara yes i need the instant search result in google. which populating via javascript. and not getting it in file_get_contents or curl method. else i saved the search result page manually i can access the elements inside google instant search result.

so if i can save the pages into local, then i can go through all the downloaded or saved contents in local machine. and find out what i need

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use php curl to download the HTML from that page.

After that you need to scrape the content of images, css, js and other files and download and save them conserving the path, by using readfile() function.